# Plot sublists as different colors

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, color

I have one big list with many sublists inside. All sublists consist of three numbers. For example:

```
{{83, 85, 82}, {65, 49, 46}, {65, 76, 45}, {70, 65, 84}, {73, 72, 65}, {40, 84, 72}, {69, 79, 80}, {69, 78, 73}, {78, 71, 41}, {10, 10, 49}}
```

This is part of a list and I want that each sublist is one point on graphic. For example RGB(83,85,82) is color of first pixel, then 65,49,46 is color of the next pixel and so on.

Is there any way to plot that list in such way that one sublist represents one color in RGB system and somehow to specify the width of a plot. Thanks.

Comment: You can't post a small section of your "big list"?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Press F1, search for `Plot`, `ListPlot`, `ImageSize` and `PlotStyle`. Otherwise, please specify clearly what you want to do.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you if you don't give an example of what you're having a hard time with?

Comment: {{83, 85, 82}, {65, 49, 46}, {65, 76, 45}, {70, 65, 84}, {73, 72, 65}, {40, 84, 72}, {69, 79, 80}, {69, 78, 73}, {78, 71, 41}, {10, 10, 49}} This is part of a list and I want that each sublist is one point on graphic. For example RGB(83,85,82) is color of first pixel, then 65,49,46 is color of the next pixel and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say your data is:

```
q = {{{1, 85, 82}, {65, 49, 1}, {65, 76, 255}, {70, 65, 84}, {73, 266, 65}, 
      {40, 84, 72}, {69, 79, 80}, {69, 78, 73}, {78, 71, 41}, {10, 10, 49}}}
```

Note that I added another level of list so that it would be in the proper form. Then you can display it as an image using the oddly named `Image` command:

```
Image[q, "Byte", ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

The option `ImageSize` controls how large the image is. The form "Byte" is used to specify that your data is in the form of integers in the range 0-255 rather than the more common 0-1 range.

You can read all about these kind of commands by taking a word like `Image` and pressing the F1 (help) key. There are lots of options to choose from. If you wan to learn more about this kind of thing, the [image processing tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImageProcessing.html) is pretty good.

For example, you can arrange the pixel values in a 2D array. Here we construct a random set of values in a 2 row by 5 column array, each of which is specified by a 3-tuple of values, and then visualize using `Image`

```
w = RandomInteger[{1, 255}, {2, 5, 3}]
Image[w, "Byte", ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want, thank you :D

Comment: I have my list inside list1 and when I added another level of list list2={list1} and tried Image[list2, "Byte", ImageSize -> 100] I only got big blank output.

Comment: Look at the form I used above, and make sure the lists are nested properly.

Comment: In your example you have 10 pixels, I would like to put those pixels in two rows 5 in each.

Comment: Try this one: `q = {{{1, 85, 82}, {65, 49, 1}, {65, 76, 255}, {70, 65, 84}, {73, 266, 65}}, {{40, 84, 72}, {69, 79, 80}, {69, 78, 73}, {78, 71, 41}, {10, 10, 49}}}` I've now made it a matrix of 3-tuples, which is the needed form. Or try this one: `q = RandomReal[1, {2, 5, 3}]` You can find this last example in the help file for `Image`.

Comment: That works, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Generate some friendly colors (your list works just as well, but keep in mind that you usually want RGB values between 0 and 1 for `Raster`):

```
colors = Table[List @@ ToColor[Hue[h], RGBColor], {h, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

> ```
> (*{{1., 0., 0.}, {1., 0.6, 0.}, {0.8, 1., 0.}, {0.2, 1., 0.}, {0., 1., 
>   0.4}, {0., 1., 1.}, {0., 0.4, 1.}, {0.2, 0., 1.}, {0.8, 0., 
>   1.}, {1., 0., 0.6}, {1., 0., 0.}}*}
> ```

```
Graphics[Raster[Transpose[List /@ (colors)]], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: I want the Image Uploader back NOW!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another method.  With your RGB data in `a`:

```
SeedRandom[3]
a = RandomInteger[255, {10, 3}]
```

Merely:

```
ArrayPlot[{255 - a}]
```

[image]

Or split on two rows:

```
ArrayPlot[ Partition[255 - a, 5] ]
```

[image]

See [ArrayPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayPlot.html) for options.

Comment: darn - short *and* sweet!

Comment: @Yves Thanks! :-)

Comment: Now there's a function that would be useful: `SplitInto[lst, n]` or `PartitionInto[lst, n]` where it would partition a list into `n` sublists of equal length. Additional settings would be needed to deal with non-divisible splits, but that's just details. +1, btw.

Comment: @rcollyer you mean [like this?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9264869#9264869)

Comment: @rcollyer yes, Partition is already up to that - I always struggle to remember the syntax, though :-)

Comment: @Yves do you mean my use with e.g. `Ceiling` or something native to `Partition` itself I'm overlooking?

Comment: Exactly. It just needed packaging.

Comment: @YvesKlett I did not think it was directly up to that. I thought it required some pre-processing first (based on list length, etc.) to work.

Comment: No, your solution is dandy. I misread @rcollyer wish list and thought he was just after the Partition[lst, #, #, 1, {}] part which I always struggle to remember (gotta bookmark this!). Sorry for arousing false hopes!

Comment: @YvesKlett no, just wanted nice packaging for it. :)